WebSocket server not receiving messages that have been sent by the client
I'm trying to implement chat in my spring-boot app using websocket. After launching app, then opening MessagesActivity, my test message is sent. I can see in Logcat that connection with server was established and webSocket.send("test message") returns 'true' but server is not showing any data in logs. Both client and server are written in java. I am using okhttp3.WebSocketListener to handle onOpen, onMessage, etc. methods. The test message sends and returns correctly when I'm using WebSocket Echo Server instead of my server.
MessagesActivity class:
public class MessagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebSocketClient webSocketClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_messages);

        webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient();
    }
}

WebSocketClient:
public WebSocketClient() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://10.0.2.2:8080/chat").build();

        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, okhttp3.Response response) {
                super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
                Log.d("WebSocket", "Connection established");
                webSocket.send("test message");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
                Log.d("WebSocket", "Received message: " + text);
            }

            // other methods
        });
    }


WebSocketConfig on server:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}

ChatController on server:
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/chat")
    public String get(@Payload String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
        return text;
    }
}

Main class on server:
@SpringBootApplication
public class CleanTServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CleanTServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
}

